# How to find data rule/condition using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I want to find rules or conditions from my data.

For example, if I say find the condition from single column like this below,
it will be [Column1 > 2]

| Column1 | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | False |
| 2 | False |
| 3 | True |
| 4 | True |

Another example, if I say find the condition from two columns like this below,
it will be [Column1 > 1 and Column2 > 1]

| Column1 | Column1 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | False |
| 2 | 1 | False |
| 1 | 2 | False |
| 2 | 2 | True |

and below will be [Column1 > 1 or Column2 > 3]

| Column1 | Column1 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | False |
| 2 | 3 | True |
| 1 | 4 | True |
| 2 | 4 | True |

I think I found the solution with two columns, but I don't know how to write the code when over 3 columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
true_list = df.query("result = 'True'")
false_list = df.query("result = 'False'")

condition = find_condition(true_list, false_list)
print(condition)
# Column1 > 1 or Column1 > Column2 ..

def find_condition(t_list, f_list):
    # do something...
```

Please help me somebody has an idea.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you considered `df.where`?

Comment: I think df.where is not helpful (in my knowledge). I am trying to write function that make data condition automatically.

Comment: Condition automatically as in you just give the conditions in the first place, and you will get a result column with desired output?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning). afaik, numpy has no module to generalize the conditions with given input and output data.

Comment: I tried find information from ml and not very helpful. I tried to use tensorflow, but its only predict things, not finding the conditions and even prediction is not correct (If there is way to find condition of data using tensorflow, please tell me)

Comment: Maybe try ['sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree). You can inspect the decision tree after fitting to your data.